# Two Way data Binding in Angular js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am using nodejs + Angular  and html as a froentend

Here is my HTML  Code

```
<div id="container" ng-app='two_way' ng-controller='two_way_control'>
      <div class="row" ng-repeat="data in profile_pictures">
        <div class=".col-sm-6 .col-md-5 .col-lg-6" style="background-color:#eee;height:150px;width:500px;margin-left:240px;margin-top:20px;">
          <h4 style="padding:10px;">User Say's</h4><hr>
          <img src="{{data.profile_picture}}" class="img-circle" style="width:100px;height:100px;margin-left:-140px;margin-top:-130px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and  my angular code is here

```
app.controller('two_way_control',function($scope,$http,$interval){
  load_pictures();
  $interval(function(){
    load_pictures();
  },300);
  function load_pictures(){
  $http.get('http://localhost:3000/load').success(function(data){    
    $scope.profile_pictures=data;
  });
  };
});
```

and my server code is

```
app.get('/load',function(req,res){
  connection.query("SELECT * from user_info",function(err,rows){
    if(err)
      {
        console.log("Problem with MySQL"+err);
      }
      else
        {
          res.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
        }
  });
});
```

Which is working fine..

When i entered a new record in **user_info*. it will display new record to me.

Is this right way to do two way data binding or i am missing something

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you're doing one way binding because your angular code is never modifying the profiles pictures in the table (meaning you ain't got no form fields, your page is read only). But AFAIK you're doing everything right, as soon as you add editing capabilities to your angular page you would be doing two way binding all the way

Comment: Can you give me example for that pls

Comment: i want to do two way binding

Answer (score 1):

YES! Angular '2-way bind' is between scope.variable and VIEW (ng-model in input elements).
In this case, the SRC property of IMG element need to be setd with ng-src!
Because IMG is a html element that load before angular principal scripts.

```
<div id="container" ng-app='two_way' ng-controller='two_way_control'>
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="data in profile_pictures">
    <div class=".col-sm-6 .col-md-5 .col-lg-6" style="background-color:#eee;height:150px;width:500px;margin-left:240px;margin-top:20px;">
      <h4 style="padding:10px;">User Say's</h4><hr>
      <img ng-src="{{data.profile_picture}}" class="img-circle" style="width:100px;height:100px;margin-left:-140px;margin-top:-130px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do u want 2-way bind with the server side (nodejs)?

Comment: yes.. when anything on server side, i want it automatically reflect on froentend .

Comment: That way u post works, but is not a real 2-way bind with server.

Comment: To do a real 2-way bind with the server, u need the server notify clients for each change.

Comment: http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/push-notification-server-streaming-on-a-mysql-database/ This friend do something like u want

Comment: may be.. not sure.. But then what is the benefit to do two way binding  on frontend

Comment: 2-way bind is between control e inputModels... When u change value property from a input that have ng-model associated with some scope variable, this will update.

Comment: In my case, a common use Ms-SqlServer, to do 2-way bind with database, i need to do a web socket server that notify the changes using SQL Service Broker

Comment: Can't we do without push notification

Comment: :-( NOPE! Think about it. U can't know if u have changes in your db without a notification.
Without notification, the only way is a timer with query to update.

Comment: I agree for this. But sending interval each time is not a good idea. and using Web socket will slow down the appplication and sometime give socket hang out error

Comment: Because it principal database systems have query notify services.
To help, see: 
SQL Server:Query notify [link](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/)
ORACLE: [link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359%5F01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns%5Fcqn.htm)
MYSQL: doesnt have query notify, but that friend do something cool with mysql

Comment: HTML5 web socket works fine. Is the best way to do realtime applications.

Comment: If u can change the database. Now we have the https://www.firebase.com - Is a database with 2-way bind support ANGULAR.JS compatible.

Comment: Behind FIREBASE runs web socket

Comment: i have no idea about that. can u please explain more..  i dnt want to use socket.io and  i need mysql

Comment: Without web socket u can't do real 2-way bind... only 1-way bind, with a timer to update query. Because we haven't other way to update client site.